# A web application running in JBoss EAP through Eclipse cannot be accessed from another computer in the same network

Tags: eclipse, windows, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a web application (JSF2) running in JBoss EAP through Eclipse in my machine (Computer1). Computer1 is a Windows7 machine.
I can run the application using the Eclipse Internal Browser and Chrome in Computer1.
But when I try to access the application from another computer (Computer2) in the same network, I receive a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error message.

I saw using netstat that Computer1 is listening at port 8080 and Computer1 has no firewall.

I can ping at Computer1 from Computer2.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JBoss is listening to the *local* interface only. A quick search reveals that you have to add an interface to your configuration, e.g.:

```
<interfaces>  
    ...
    <interface name="any">  
        <any-address/>  
    </interface>  
</interfaces>
```

And then configure the `socket-binding-group` to use it:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="any">
```

Reference: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/168789